# SnowflakeDbConnection Open(): Randomly fails after upgrade to .NET Standard 2.1

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-standard, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I upgraded a solution from projects that had **.NET Core 2.2** and **.NET Standard 2.0** to **.NET Core 3.0** and **.NET Standard 2.1**, respectively.

In the project built with the .NET Standard framework, there is a line of code that is presenting issues that wasn't before

```
private _connectionString = " stuff here ";

public List<Character> GetAll(int take, int skip, string orderBy, string sortOrder)
{   
    ...
    using (IDbConnection conn = new SnowflakeDbConnection())
    {

        conn.ConnectionString = _connectionString;

        if (conn != null && conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            conn.Close();

        try {
            conn.Open();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    ...
}
```

When the code reaches `conn.Open()`, it just hangs until finally returning

> TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.

and it gives no further information than that. What is odd is that the first time this method was invoked, it actually worked just fine. Then I refreshed the page and its been broken since. Until I sat for sometime and it returned again with the correct data -- and then randomly broke upon a refresh or another build of the solution.

I suspect the upgrade of the framework is only coincidental and that this is more likely an issue with the connection source server/database?

---

**UPDATE:** After running `SYSTEM$WHITELIST()` on Snowflake, copying the json result and saving it to file called `whitelist.json`, I ran the following command on my local machine:

```
snowcd .\whitelist.json
Performing 33 checks for 13 hosts
All checks passed
```

Comment: a) Use `throw;` rather than `throw ex;` b) Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Where does `SnowflakeDbConnection` come from? Have they upgraded to corresponding 3.0/standard 2.1?

Comment: Seems like it may be an error with the connection string. There are multiple reported issues with the same error when opening a connection with `SnowflakeDbConnection`: https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-net/issues/160, https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-net/issues/97

Answer (score 2):

You can add the account name on your connection string host entry just like:

```
conn.ConnectionString = "account =accountName;
host=accountName.region.azure.snowflakecomputing.com;User=userName;
password=password;db=dBName;schema=scehmaName;";
```

Add the log4Net in the code so you will get the detail snowflake exception so you can easily identify the actual cause.

Comment: This fixed it for me and it makes sense. My current snowflake host is "<account>.us-east-1.snowflakecomputing.com". The docs say if host is not specified it tries to use "<account>.snowflakecomputing.com", which is incorrect. https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-net